# Skip reporting errors when using @ ( Error Control Operators )

Tags: php, error-handling

My code is:

```
function errors($number,$string,$file,$line)
{
    $error = $string.' In '.$file.', on line '.$line."\n";
    error_log($error);
}
set_error_handler('errors',E_ALL);
```

The next line stop showing an error because I'm using the `@` operator. But, my problem is that `set_error_handler` write the error in the `error.log` file.

```
echo @$undefined_variable; // I don't want to write this error in error.log file
```

Comment: How about writing better code so that variable is never undefined? That's the *right* solution.

Comment: I don't want to do this. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Your handler ought to probe the current level with `error_reporting()` itself. Once registered it's called every time. The `@` does not actually suppress errors, just adapt the reporting level (for the built-in handler to eschew display of messages).

Comment: You can also set defaults so that your variables are never undefined. `function errors($number = -1, $string = '', $file = '', $line = -1)`. If you really want to ignore, use `@echo $undefined_variable;`.

Answer (score 1):

Although a better solution would be to fix the undefined variable problem you can do what you're asking for like this:

```
ini_set('log_errors', false);
echo $undefined_variable;
ini_set('log_errors', true);
```

Again, I strongly urge you to fix the problem (either define the variable or check it with isset before using it) instead of masking the error.